# Why is using extends in TypeScript giving me an `any` type?

Tags: typescript

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgThCNwQDwwHxQLxQN4BQUUANhAGbAD8AXLAkiuhkVHAJYDmAFtXfImSRmrAG4BDEgFcI-AgF8CBUJHqIAqgDsA7nHFhIcIWkw5YUCAA9gETQBMAzmsbD2m8hDhQAGi2JUfVjpNCFFPJRVoAQgAQRJ2cQdjZjMYC2tbR2dktw8vX1YA73SbeycAewAjACsIAGNgVn9YJqhg0PDidrC4CJQodQdPYzNCYggAW3F2EjoHYA5NTgUlOvLNeagFxH4GZMHhlCxcMagJaVl8CymZugBycnLygAFK8TgAOjWJu6h5ABoVgQ1htgFApEM4LsNDo9AZDsJovtIcYMMd8KxJtNZlAHk9Xu8vuUfoDFMD1ptthAAEzQ2LxRLJJFMA5GI7o07nGR0PDXbH3R4vN6fb6-AFAyJQADKa0gySl-ygAAUSpknFJNABrTTlbSaMwa7W6zQc1h2cTAcR0KWsMDvWx8ZWqsrS2UuNC5TywRWerwART8xCgARl5TlTBgioDrW64TJkqV5QcDnYlTIofDwilplw2edWQz7tQrF90sBxFLKqspQLbpy7i9MR9Da8ACEWIGQ2kAD5O3uJ5Op9N1phKwOx3rKfoAWXKdikZBGJ1tFu4cwWbmWZJBmwcbutI+Es-ni6OozNFqtGKDUDtwDXuI+AHpBR9LHdy39SasKWC92GaQPADkQRCBFULZJjwXd00XPYhzUtHlWixW5cUFAkRWJD9WHFYg7QQTRgDmN1vwIMg-zdABmOgBxTNMIAgphGKPOdoNRdF-0gakCE4iBKLMXieKoswFhkJQrDAco4DBBN7UI5i0CldEpXzJwFOLCsWx8T9KxtTtpSgfsVP7OTgHUpUlKCaVxMsSTpK2folVMhTqVQJSzBU6s1VdYCmBLLTvB0rSAE1VJ8zMPS0psoFLdsCH0m0umssiID-copDgOpLkLOIEiSJhInKcgoF4rBew1OwKDcCA7AEt1uIICSpJk-ocoZfKs3RJyCLMw9FJYIA) is my TypeScript playground, which has this:

```
type TreeType<T> = {
  left?: TreeType<T>
  right?: TreeType<T>
  value: T
}

type TreeUnwrapperType<T> = T extends TreeType<infer X>
  ? X
  : never

type TreeAliasType<T> = T extends TreeType<infer X>
  ? X extends object
    ? T
    : never
  : never

type UserType = {
  email: string
}

const tree: TreeType<UserType> = {
  value: { email: 'foo@bar.com' },
}

const user: TreeUnwrapperType<TreeType<UserType>> = {
  email: 'foo@bar.com',
}

const tree2: TreeAliasType<TreeType<UserType>> = {
  value: { email: 'foo@bar.com' },
}

type ScopeType<S, P extends unknown = unknown> = {
  data: S
  parent?: P extends ScopeType<infer T, infer Q>
    ? ScopeType<T, Q>
    : never
}

type PossibleScopeType<ST> = ST extends ScopeType<
  infer S,
  infer P extends ScopeType<infer A, infer B>
>
  ? ST | P | PossibleScopeType<P>
  : never

type ModuleType = {
  path: string
}

const scope: ScopeType<ModuleType> = {
  data: {
    path: './foo.x',
  },
}

const scope2: ScopeType<UserType, ScopeType<ModuleType>> = {
  data: {
    email: 'foo@bar.com',
  },
  parent: scope,
}

let scope3: PossibleScopeType<ScopeType<ModuleType>> = scope2
scope3 = scope
scope3 = true

export type ParentScopeType<S> = S extends ScopeType<
  infer X,
  infer PS
>
  ? S | PS | ParentScopeType<PS>
  : S

export type ParentScopeType2<S> = S extends ScopeType<
  infer X,
  infer Y extends ScopeType<infer A, infer B>
>
  ? S
  : S

let source: ScopeAliasType<typeof scope> | undefined = scope2

export type ScopeAliasType<S> = ParentScopeType<S>
```

In that (I am messing around trying to figure something out), this section has `scope3` typed as `any` for some reason:

```
let scope3: PossibleScopeType<ScopeType<ModuleType>> = scope2
scope3 = scope
scope3 = true
```

[image]

The `PossibleScopeType` I am trying to have it return all the linked parents in the tree, but instead it is returning `any`, even though I have defined it like this:

```
type PossibleScopeType<ST> = ST extends ScopeType<
  infer S,
  infer P extends ScopeType<infer A, infer B>
>
  ? ST | P | PossibleScopeType<P>
  : never
```

What am I doing wrong?

- Why is it returning `any` type for `scope3`?
- How do I make `PossibleScopeType` make it so `scope3` is typed as either scope2 or it's parent, scope1, in a dynamic way? (I.e. not hardcoding to this specific case)

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgThCNwQDwwHxQLxQN4BQUUANhAGbAD8AXLAkiuhkVHAJYDmAFtXfImSRmrAG4BDEgFcI-AgF8CBUJHqIAqgDsA7nHFhIcIWkw5YUCAA9gETQBMAzmsbD2m8hDhQAGi2JUfVjpNCFFPJRVoAQgAQRJ2cQdjZjMYC2tbR2dktw8vX1YA73SbeycAewAjACsIAGNgVn9YJqhg0PDidrC4CJQodQdPYzNCYggAW3F2EjoHYA5NTgUlOvLNeagFxH4GZMHhlCxcMagJaVl8CymZugBycnLygAFK8TgAOjWJu6h5ABoVgQ1htgFApEM4LsNDo9AZDsJovtIcYMMd8KxJtNZlAHk9Xu8vuUfoDFMD1ptthAAEzQ2LxRLJJFMA5GI7o07nGR0PDXbH3R4vN6fb6-AFAyJQADKa0gySl-ygAAUSpknFJNABrTTlbSaMwa7W6zQc1h2cTAcR0KWsMDvWx8ZWqsrS2UuNC5TywRWerwART8xCgARl5TlTBgioDrW64TJkqV5QcDnYlTIofDwilplw2edWQz7tQrF90sBxFLSoIgZDaQAPk6rKUC26cu4vTEfe2vAAhLABFUNxPJ1Pp1tMJVYWO9LpQEI9PqqACy5TsUjIIxOtot3DmCzcyzJIM2Djd1vHwhXa43R1GZotVoxQagduAu9xHwA9IKPpY7uW-lJVYKTBU8wxpc9wORBEIEVQtkivdd3TRO9iHNS0eVaLFblxQUCRFYl-1YcViDtBBNGAOY3SAggyFAt0AGY6GHFM0wgeCmA4y9VyQ1F0TAyBqQIASIAYswROExizAWGQlCsMByjgMEE3tCiuLQKV0SlfMnHU4sK27HwAMrG0a2lKAh20odVOAPSlU0oJpTkywFKUrZ+iVGz1OpVBNLMbSmzVV0oKYEtDO8YzDIATR04LMw9QzOygUs+2rQonNnG1aIgUDyikOA6kuQs4gSJImEicpyCgESsAbDU7AoNwIDscS3SEgh5MU5T+mKhkyqzdFPPI2yLw0lggA) is another variant.

Comment: In your playground link, the playground indicates that "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" for the type that is being widened to `any`.

Comment: Weird, it was not showing any errors for me? Now it seems to show me errors, alright I changed it (last link in post now).